# the field not updated

Tags: trigger

```
trigger LeadStatusCheck on Lead ( before update)
{
      List<String> leadEmails = new List<String>();
    for(Lead lead:Trigger.new){
        leadEmails.add(lead.Email);
    }

    List<Contact> contacts = [ SELECT  Id, Email  FROM  Contact WHERE Email =:leadEmails ];

    Set<String> contactEmails = new Set<String>();
    for(Contact contact:contacts){
        contactEmails.add(contact.Email);
        system.debug('contact mail='+ contact.Email);
    }
    Contact con=new Contact();
    for(Lead lead:Trigger.new){
        if(contactEmails.contains(lead.Email))
           {
               system.debug('lead mail='+lead.Email);

                   con.Lead_Status__c =lead.Status;// here i'm assign the value of field ...but value not assign
               system.debug('lead status='+lead.Status);
                   try
                   {
                 update con;
                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       system.debug(con.Lead_Status__c);
                   }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hi.im find the solution of this trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295084/hi-im-find-the-solution-of-this-trigger)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to update a contact without giving it an id, there is no way Salesforce can understand which contact to Update.

**Issues with the above code :**

- You need to create a Map of Email to Contact record and in the for
  loop if the contact email is equal to lead email, take the contact
  record from the map and update its field, this will give reference to
  the contact for which you want to update Lead_Status__c field.
- You are creating Contact instance outside of the loop, this will only
  create one contact record. Needs bulkification to handle multple
  records in trigger.
- Update con is inside a for loop, which can hit the governor limits,
  need to be bulkified.

You code should be something like below :

```
Map<String,Contact> emailToContactMap = new Map<String,Contact>();
List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();//Contacts to be updated 
for(Contact contact:contacts){
    emailToContactMap.put(contact.Email,contact);
    system.debug('contact mail='+ contact.Email);
}
//Contact con=new Contact(); this line is not required, as you will get the contact record from map emailToContactMap
for(Lead lead:Trigger.new){
    if(emailToContactMap.contains(lead.Email))
       {
           system.debug('lead mail='+lead.Email);

            Contact contactRec = emailToContactMap.get(lead.Email);// here we are getting the contact record for the email and updating it in the next line
            contactRec.Lead_Status__c =lead.Status;

           system.debug('lead status='+lead.Status);

           contactList.add(contactRec);

    }
}
if(!contactList.isEmpty()){
    update contactList;
}
```

Comment: here some error on line number 4

Comment: i dnt run the code just gave you the snippet, can you tell me the exact error

Comment: I remove the error....thank you so much for this code